# Getting Serenity HTML reports during execution

Tags: test-report, serenity-bdd

I am using Serenity with Cucumber. Here the HTML report created for each scenario is with a random string.

My questions:

1. Can we rename those individual HTML report by scenario name?.
2. Is the HTML report generated right after the scenario is completed? Or after the whole execution?
3. If an answer to the 2nd question is yes can someone please explain the report generation flow?
4. Can we get the result during runtime? Or only at the end of the test run?

My requirement is to get test results parallel as soon as each test/scenario/feature is completed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The report is generated by running `mvn serenity:aggregate` and is based on your surefire/failsafe report. Usually you call this at the end of your whole test suite.

I would suggest you provide quicker feedback by watching the `target/surefire-reports/.*xml` files. The these are created after each class executed. If you really need html reports, you can theoretically create a report after each executed class. I am convinced, this is to much overhead though.

Another strategy would be to use [execution in parallel batches](https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/serenity-parallel-batches.html#_configuring_parallel_batch_execution_with_jenkins_1) with every batch running a `aggregate` and publishing the result.